# redirecting html page extension to php extension with parameters using htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is what I trying to achieve.
I want to redirect something like this

```
http://www.example.com/news/news-seo-title-with-unicode-maybe.html
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/news.php?seo_url=news-seo-title-with-unicode-maybe.php
```

This is what I have written in my htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ $1.php?seo_url=$2 [L]
```

I am being redirected to news.php but there are nothing in $_GET variable. Is there any mistake in my htaccess code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ $1.php?seo_url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`. It needs to be turned off for GET parameter to be passed in.